# Retrieve the name on a website?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code which is in HTML;

```
<div id="progress_info" class="success" style="display: block;">
‌·‌·‌·
<div id="error_text" style="display: none;"></div>
‌·‌·‌·
<div id="image" style="display: block;">
‌·‌·‌·
<div style="float:left; max-width:330px">
‌·‌·‌·
<div id="status_text" style="display: block;">Video‌·successfully‌·converted‌·to‌·mp3</div>
‌·‌·‌·
<div id="title" style="display: block;">
    <b>Title:</b>
‌    Developers
</div>
‌·‌·‌·
<div id="length" style="display: block;">
‌·‌·‌·
<div id="link_box" style="display:none">
‌·‌·‌·
<div id="v-ads"></div>
‌·‌·‌·
<div id="dl_link" style="display: block;">
‌·‌·‌·
<div id="progress" style="display: none;"></div>
‌·‌·‌·
<div id="loader" style="display: none;">
‌·‌·‌·
</div>
```

and I am just wondering how I would retrieve the title (name of song) known as "Developers" via webBrowser1 control in c#?

I tried searching this question and there were no questions and/or answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i have achieved the same thing.

```
 HtmlElementCollection oHtmlElementCollection;
        public List<string> lstDetailsUrl = new List<string>();
                            oHtmlElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
                            lstDetailsUrl.Clear();
                            for (int i = 0; i < oHtmlElementCollection.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (oHtmlElementCollection[i].GetAttribute("id") != null)
                                {
                                    if (oHtmlElementCollection[i].GetAttribute("id").Contains("title"))
                                    {
                                        lstDetailsUrl.Add(oHtmlElementCollection[i].InnerText);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: So it is going through the list and looking for the div id = title, then it gets its inner text aka the name of the song?

Comment: Yes, you will get <b>Title:</b> ·Developers in the value and then you can manipulate the using some Regex.

Comment: Hmm, I tested this and I get the text "DirectLink"? Only reason I want this is due to I am downloading a song via a website, and now I am handling the download event and I cannot save the song automatically without a name, thus I am trying to grab the name before it downloads and saves automatically, unless I can get the name via the pop up of when you must save the file? Either way, thank you as I will look into this further.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the HTML Agility Pack with good results: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

You'll just need to use the WebBrowser control to get the HTML source of the page first (webBrowser1.DocumentText)